# Extracting path from PrimeVue's menuitem

Tags: primevue

I am looking to determine path based on clicked MenuItem in PrimeVue.

MenuItem.to is defined as `to?: RouteLocationRaw | undefined;` and `RouteLocationRaw` is defined as `export declare type RouteLocationRaw = string | RouteLocationPathRaw | RouteLocationNamedRaw`

So `to` can be one of three different types.

What is best way to extract the string representation of the MenuItem - I see option 1 to use MenuItem.to.String() or to create user-define typeguards returning type predicate which seems to way too much overkill.

Looking for some ideas.